# Issue downloading zip file using httpwebrequest, Parameter name: size

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I had problems downloading rar file before, server is not configured for rar, so I decided to give a go zip and here again another issue. I have added an exception and get message like this: "Specified argument was out the range of valid values. Parameter name:size"
File is about 100KB. 
Looking forward for you help, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://webserver.com/test/zip")
request.CookieContainer = logincookie
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 Java/1.7.0"
request.Method = "GET"
response = request.GetResponse()
If Not response.ContentType = "application/zip" Then
MsgBox("Error: " & ErrorToString() & vbCrLf & "Current file name is : " & response.ContentType.ToString)
Exit Sub
End If
Dim intLen As Int32 = response.ContentLength
Dim memStream As MemoryStream
Using stmResponse As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim buffer = New Byte(intLen) {}
Dim bytesRead As Integer
Do
bytesRead += stmResponse.Read(buffer, bytesRead, intLen - bytesRead)
Loop Until bytesRead = intLen
memStream = New MemoryStream(buffer)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("test.zip", buffer, False)
End Using 
End If
```

Comment: Checked content length to string and got -1...

Comment: It seems you found your bug, Is your question still valid?

Answer (score 0):

*Why `ContentLength` is -1?* it may be that the server returns data in chunks (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`)

Since your original question included a `c#` tag, I'll answer it using c#, without using *ContentLength*

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(""http://webserver.com/test/zip") as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 Java/1.7.0";
request.Method = "GET";
var response = request.GetResponse();

var stmResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
stmResponse.CopyTo(memStream);
byte[] buffer = memStream.ToArray();
```